# tkinter deiconify() method does not draw window in the same location (on linux)

Tags: python, tkinter

The problem is on linux (ubuntu 16.04). On windows, it works correctly.

When I `withdraw()` the main window and later `deiconify()` it, the window gets shifted (up) by a small amount. If I reset the `geometry` before the `deiconify` call, it still doesn't work as expected. What can I do to prevent the shifting of the window?

Following is the code -

```
def win():
    def run_again():
        root.deiconify()
        root.after(6000, run_again)

    root = Tk()

    root.title('Reminder')
    root.geometry('-0-40')
    root.minsize(width=300,height=100)
    root.attributes("-topmost", True)
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    Label(root, text='test').grid(padx=20, pady=20, sticky=NW)
    btn = Button(root, text='Ok', command=root.withdraw)
    btn.grid(pady=5)
    btn.bind('<Return>', lambda e: root.quit())

    root.withdraw()
    root.after(6000, run_again)
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", root.withdraw)
    root.mainloop()

win()
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem in archlinux.

Comment: Are you getting the window redrawn in the same location each time?

Comment: Yes, it is redrawn exactly at the same position, I have used the border of another window as reference.

Comment: Then maybe it's Ubuntu because the shift is clearly happening in my case.

Comment: Maybe it is because ubuntu 16.04 uses an older version of tkinter than archlinux.

Comment: Try calling `root.iconify()` immediately before `root.deiconify()` maybe.

Comment: @Nae I get the same result.

Comment: There is a definite upward shift on Ubuntu 16.04 with both Python 3.5 and Python 3.6.

Comment: Maybe that depends on the desktop environment, I am using XFCE and I noticed no shift.